# Python Tex tfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to store the inputs in my text file every time I run it. But when I run the script the old inputs gets deleted! how can I fix this?

sample code:

name = input('Enter name: ')

f = open('test.txt', 'w')

f.write(name)

f.close()

Answer (score 1):

You should open the file in [append mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```py
f = open('test.txt', 'at')
```

Notice the `at`, meaning `append text`. You have `w` mode, meaning `write text` (text is default), which first truncates the file. This is why your old inputs got deleted.

Answer (score 1):

With the 'w' in the open() you create a new empty file everytime.
use open('test.txt', 'a+')

Also I would suggest you use the with statement:

```
name = input('Enter name: ')

with open('test.txt', 'a+') as file:
    file.write(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

write the additional text in append mode

```
f = open('test.txt', 'a')
```

'w' is write mode and so deletes any other data before rewriting any new data